# Python Program with Save Feature

Tags: python, save

I am making a program that will allow a user to create a certain modifiable list. The goal is to allow a user to create a schedule, which can be loaded and modified later. Is it possible to somehow save what a user has done so they can open up the program later and continue where they left off?

This would be similar to the way one can make a document in a word processor, save the document, close the word processor, come back later, and open up the document to continue modifying it.

I would essentially like to save the current session or instance of the program, with all the variables and such stored in a file while the program is not running. They can then be accessed the next time the program is launched and the specific file is selected and "opened" in the program.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a database.
I recommend to play around with the SQlite which is an SQL-based relational database system. Is very easy and dynamic system and has great connectivity with the programming language Python.

I recommend read first about the SQLite [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/) and then how to connect an SQLite database to python [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm)

You can create tables to store your information and then creating the appropriate UI you can give to the user the ability to load their data to the program again.

**Example**
I didn't actually understand your program idea, but Iets think a simple example of an application that enables the user to create appointments.

The user can set time of the appointment, the date and the place as well as some short description.

As you can see we can have a table appointment in our database with fields (columns):
`id , date, time, place and description` .

```
Appointment table
----------------------------------------------------
Id   | Date        | Time   | Place   | Description |
1    | 02/6/15   | 20:00  | A place| desc1          |
2    | 03/6/15   | 15:00  | B place| desc2          |
----------------------------------------------------
```

So now you can use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Appointment;
```

This will return you two tuples of data from the above table, and so you can represent your data as you wish in a UI.

Another option is to use flat files , but using a database will be more easy and dynamic and error free.

Comment: Backticks are for code, commands, etc, not any and every technical term. "flat files" can be called "flat files", formatted just that way -- they're English jargon, not code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a database is overkill here, as they often are. This program sounds like it's going to be storing a handful of objects of one or two types. You should just dump json to a flat file; define a function that takes all your state objects and a file object and writes the objects as json to the file, and then write another that parses the objects from the file. Bam, you're done.